# silverstripe starting page in db level

Tags: mysql, database, silverstripe

silverstripe has main page, which after every rebuild is created new (as home page not always suits).

How and where can i see/change this after rebuilt in mysql level (table?).
I have looked however could not find place/table/field which denotes that this is "link of home page, etc."

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is created based of requireDefaultRecords in SiteTree, this indicates that this can be stopped with a yml config (in _config/config.yml)

```
SiteTree:
    'create_default_pages' : 'false'
```

Comment: Hi,  
creating a new page is not problem, however i need to "say to cms" that a specific page is "home page" when you click banner on the left, etc.  
Where is it defined?

Comment: I'd still advise you disable it, because it is the URLSegment that this takes "home" that is the home page.  so you need those pages deleted and change the URLSegment of the page desired to be home to "home"

Answer (score 0):

In old and deprecated SilverStripe 2.4 you could define any page as homepage for a domain. However this was refactored to a module in 3.x and by default the page with URLSegment "home" is the default home page.

But you can install the functionality with the [homepage for domain](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-homepagefordomain) module, best using composer:

```
composer require silverstripe/homepagefordomain
```

which will add an input field to the cms where you can define that page as homepage for a specific domain.